# How can I get this super eye-catching color?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I'm having trouble creating this multi-colored view. It seems like my current skill level isn't enough to get the result I want. I really want to learn, but I'm not sure how to get this specific color scheme.

[image]

Comment: Add a shadow of the same color (or a simple gaussian blurred works too) around it. A sample that can inspire you: https://github.com/KrisYu/GlowLabel/blob/master/GlowingLabel.swift https://gist.github.com/mitchellporter/8eb7b75fbcaff2c6d064 etc. Not tested, but should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bars you are pointing to are nearly saturated magenta, roughly #ff64ff. However, they also have a bit of linear gradient on them to give them the tube shape, and a magenta "shadow" to give them glow effect. How to get them would be very dependent on the system you are using to draw them.